# How to install packages in android sdk in offline mode

Tags: android

I would like to know about the way installing packages in offline mode using android sdk

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by offline mode? 
If the apk file is already downloaded/present, you can install

Comment: i mean that how to install packages in android sdk manager without internet connection

Comment: If you have apk in download folder.. you can use this as ,  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "test.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);